# Using Predicate in gremlin javascript

Tags: node.js, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I want to use **gremlin-javascript** to traverse the remote graph and get a list of vertex, whose id is within a list of predefined ids.

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
const GraphPredicate = gremlin.process.P;
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

const graph = new Graph();
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin'));

g.V()
    .has('id', GraphPredicate.within([414, 99999]))
    .toList()
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Above are the codes I have tried, but it gave me an empty list of vertex, whereas, I expected to have a *vertex(414)* in the result.

Moreover, when I tested with the gremlin-console by using the statement below, it gave me the *vertex(414)* in the result.

```
:> g.V().hasId(within(414,99999))
```

So I have some questions here:

- Do I miss something in the configuration in order to use Predicate?
- In the method of javascript ***GraphPredicate.within([414, 99999]))*** is the parameter supposed to be **only an array of elements** or **a list of elements separated by a comma** as in the case with gremlin-console? By the way, I have tried both ways, but I always got an empty result.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 3):

The id is an special property in TinkerPop and can't be retrieved using the name property `"id"`.

The correct way to retrieve by ids in your case should be:

```
g.V().hasId(P.within(414, 99999)).toList()
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Additionally, this can be simplified by removing the `within()` call:

```
g.V().hasId(414, 99999).toList()
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Yes, your both solutions worked. However, when I applied it to filter the vertex of an edge, it seems not working. 

If I call `hasId(2, 3)` or `hasId(P.within(2,3))` just after a step `outE('LIKE').inV()` or `inE('LIKE').outV()` it will always give me an empty result, although, I am sure there should be the vertex 2, 3 in the result. Moreover, when I call with only one id `hasId(2)`, I will have the vertex 2 in the result

Comment: I agree that it is not possible to refer to **id** in the query by using simply `"id"`. However, I just happened to know that we can refer to it by using its **EnumValue**. The value can be accessed from `gremlin.process.t.id`. For instance,  `g.V().has(gremlin.process.t.id, gremlin.process.P.within([2, 3]))` will give the expected result.

Comment: @CongBangDO - in such case (as described in your first comment), you can use `as()`/`select()`. it will allow you to hold a reference to the values you *do* want to return from the traversal, and get back to these later on, before the terminal steps.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, but in order to use `id`, you need to use `gremlin.process.t.id`

Example:

in Gremlin `.by(id)`
in JS `.by(gremlin.process.t.id)`

Hope this is helpful